# PORTA installation

Tags: optimization, installation

I want to install [PORTA](https://github.com/denisrosset/porta/blob/master/INFO). I am using a win 64 bit OS. I read the installation process but I cannot really get how it works. Can anyone guide me how to install it. For example, what exactly am I supposed to do in the second step "2) Just type 'make". Type make where?

I don't know maybe I'm missing something very obvious but I got stuck

I appreciate any help in advance!!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That link on git hub is just the source files for the project.  You will have to download it (git clone or download zip) and compile it to build the executable.  You will need to open a command prompt in the gnu-make directory containing the "Makefile" and run make.  Of course, this will require that you have a compiler installed (MinGW, Cygwin, etc).  It does look like there is a Visual Studio solution in the win32 directory if you are not familiar with building with makefiles from the command line.

Comment: Thanks! I had actually downloaded the zip file. Let me install Cygwin and get myself familiar with it. I then need to do those steps in Cygwin, right?

Comment: Yes, though command line compiling often doesn't go as easy as planned.  It is a good skill to have, but you can also download Visual Studio 2017 for free and try that way.   It looks like an older version, but VS should automatically prompt you to convert/migrate it to the current version when you open the solution.

Comment: Sounds great. I installed Visual Studio. As you correctly pointed out, VS prompted me to migrate when I open the solution. However, I cannot get the .exe file when I ran a solution (e.g., valid). It gives me an error which I think it is because my OS is 64 bit while the program requires win 32 bit. I'm wounder if you think it is a windows incompatibility issue, or I'm missing something here. Thanks!!

Comment: What is the error (post the entire text)?  You should be able to go into Project-><ProjectName> Properties and verify that it is build a Win32 exe (at the top).  If it is not you can add a Win32 configuration using Project->Configuration Manager and select it in the Project Properties.